# Как сделать казино на discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу реализовать казино с помощью команды. Т.е. Если выпадает число 1 то человек проигрывает, а если 2 то его сумма удваивается. Я сделал код но он не работает, просьба помочь разобраться как сделать код для казино.

```
async def kazino(ctx,arg:int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    with open('economy.json','r') as f:
        money = json.load(f)
    random.randint(1,2)
    if random.randint == 1:
        emb = discord.Embed(title='Казино', color=discord.Color.blurple(), description=f"Вы проиграли! Выпало число 1. Может быть вам повезёт в следующий раз!")
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
        money[str(ctx.author.id)]['Money'] -= arg
    elif random.randint == 2:
        emb = discord.Embed(title='Казино', color=discord.Color.blurple(),description=f"Вы выиграли! Ваша сумма была удвоенна!")
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
        money[str(ctx.author.id)]['Money'] += arg*2
    with open('economy.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(money,f)
```

Система экономики у меня работает нормально на сервере.

Answer (score 2):

`random.randint(1,2)` выбирает какое-то число и сохраняет его в... никуда. Т.е. результат тут же отправляется в цифровую нирвану.

`if random.randint == 1` проверяет, не равна ли функция random.randint единице (внимание: не результат функции, а сама функция!). Очевидно, что не равна.

Нужно а) присвоить результат `random.randint(1,2)` какой-нибудь переменной, и б) сравнивать с 1 эту переменную.